# How does food consumption rate work?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I found that some skill bonuses are a decreased food consumption rate.  For example, Athletics -> Endurance (10 points in) *decreases* my food consumption rate by 25%.

However certain items seem to *increase* my food consumption rate, like the **Brace of Fortitude**.

Is this some sort of typo or misunderstanding on my part, or does this item intentionally make me consume food faster as a sort of trade-off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brace of Fortitude has a health regenerative bonus, so like you say, the food consumption increase is its side effect, which can be a bad thing if equiped on a Minotaur. Take the Minotaur for instance, they have an increased food consumption rate, the Insectoid have a decreased food consumption rate. Minotaurs need to eat more often, the Insectoid don't.

Your characters hunger increases whenever you move or are regeneraring health/energy, so you'll always want to store as much food as possible to keep your health regenerating.